# Unable to install Android Studio on elementary OS

Tags: development, android, ide, android-studio

I have downloaded Android Studio for Linux and extracted it using GUI.

Instructions for install are [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/revisions/b1b8efaa-98a5-4527-83dc-c02ea7e3bdbc/view-source)

The first command:

```
cd Downloads
```

puts my directory to

```
thomasshera@thomasshera-Satellite-Radius-P55W-B:~/Downloads$
```

Then the second command " ./studio.sh" gives me:

```
"bash: ./studio.sh: No such file or directory"
```

How fix this?

*EDIT 1*: Ravan, it gives me this error message;

```
ERROR: Cannot start Android Studio
No JDK found. Please validate either STUDIO_JDK, JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME environment variable points to valid JDK installation.
thomasshera@thomasshera-Satellite-Radius-P55W-B:~/Downloads/android-studio/bin$
```

*EDIT 2*: output of java -version:

```
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
* default-jre
* gcj-4.8-jre-headless
* openjdk-7-jre-headless
* gcj-4.6-jre-headless
* openjdk-6-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

*EDIT 3*: new output of `java -version` after installing JDK:

```
java version "1.7.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.3) (7u91-2.6.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.91-b01, mixed mode)
```

*EDIT 4*: response of first part of Ravan's CLI install for JDK.

> Important!!! For now, you should continue to use Java 8 because Oracle Java 9 is available as an early access release (it should be released in 2016)! You should only use Oracle Java 9 if you explicitly need it, because it may contain bugs and it might not include the latest security patches! Also, some Java options were removed in JDK9, so you may encounter issues with various Java apps. More information and installation instructions (Ubuntu / Linux Mint / Debian): http://www.webupd8.org/2015/02/install-oracle-java-9-in-ubuntu-linux.html
>    More info: https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java
>   Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

Comment: Check in the folder to see if that file exists or not. If it exists then change the file permission to make it executable. You can do it by going to the properties of the file with the right click menu or from the terminal using this command: chmod +777 /path/to/file.extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have very recently installed Android studio,

Instructions:

*GUI*:

- Download the Android Studio for linux, place it in home directory. (Not mandatory, but prefer)
- Unpack the downloaded ZIP, right click and click extract here.
- Go to `android-studio` --> `bin` --> click on `studio.sh`

CLI:

Download  the Android Studio for linux, then run the commands to install.

```
sudo apt-get install unzip #if needed.
cd [location_of_Android_Studio_zip_file]
unzip android-studio-ide-141.2456560-linux.zip # replace with your zip file name.
cd android-studio/bin/
./studio.sh
```

> "bash: ./studio.sh: No such file or directory"

You are not in correct directory. If you have Android studio in `~/Downloads` folder, you have to navigate to `~/Downloads/android-studio/bin`.

If you want to check use `file file_name` like:

*Wrong directory*:

```
ravan@ravan:~$ file studio.sh
studio.sh: ERROR: cannot open `studio.sh' (No such file or directory)
```

*Corect directory*:

```
ravan@ravan:~/android-studio/bin$ file studio.sh
studio.sh: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
```

*EDIT*:

See [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements) for system requirements. You have to install java JDK (atleast 7).

To install java:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

Comment: I used GUI to delete Android STudio download, then copied and pasted your helpful CLI version, see EDIT above for error message please.

Comment: @ThomasShera What is output of `java -version` ?

Comment: Ravan thanks for speedy response, see above.

Comment: you have to install java

Comment: I just installed JDK (sudo apt-get install default-jdk).

Comment: See new output of java -version above, thanks!

Comment: Fine now install Android studio

Comment: If I do first few lines of what you said above (first part of install) I get an error message, see above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33813/discussion-between-ravan-and-thomas-shera).